# android studio Logcat shows json data in single line and part of data

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-logcat

I used Logcat to show json data in android studio, but it just showed in single line and it couldn't show the whole json data. So how should I do can make 
Logcat show the whole json data in multi-line like eclipse?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using the `Soft Wraps`. Turn it on in the `Android Monitor` tool window. That should make it wrap the content.

[image]

Comment: Android Monitor now can be accessed from the command line only. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49574244/4254527