# How to open Android Device Monitor in latest Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I updated my android studio, after the update, I am unable to find android device monitor option in the tools section. In the previous update it was there in *tools->android->android device monitor*. But now in the updated version, it is not present. You can check screenshot of my android studio.

[image]

Comment: @Arjun  did you mean that android device monitor to open emulator or something else

Comment: @ashish no ur telling about AVD i am talking about ADM(android device monitor)

Comment: @ArjunParth what exactly you want from android monitor ? Now android studio provides much better tools instead. and you can only run android monitor from command line now.  :)

Comment: @Umair i want to push and pull files to devices from android monitor.

Answer (score 74):

If you want to push or pull your files from devices monitor now android studio offers something better then android monitor. Just take a look at right side of your studio there is an option **device file explorer**. Open it and you are good to go. Select your device from top dropdown and rest of everything is pretty much the same as it was in android monitor. Below is the screen Shot attached to give you the exact location and idea.

[image]

Comment: Yes the problem with Device file explorer is it is not recognising the older phones below or equal kitkat

Comment: @ArjunParth what is your min sdk version for the app ?

Comment: @ArjunParth I think your min sdk version is not less then kitkat that's why you are unable to see those emulators or phones.

Comment: with my case it return nothing to show. how to resolve that?

Comment: @Abdulwahid what is your min and max sdk version for your project ?

Comment: @Abdulwahid If you are using a device which has been rooted with Android Studio 3, Device File Explorer will be blank. The answer is to disable SU priviledges for adb, see;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166524/8740835

Comment: @AndrewD I saw you answer so my device was not rooted with super su  application it was rooted with king root and I  uninstalled king root. so how to solve that.

Comment: @Abdulwahid You will need to disable SU priviledges whilst using adb. I've not used KingRoot, but it looks like it has an 'advanced permissions' and 'settings' config - so I would start there. If you have uninstalled KingRoot, you will probably need to reinstall it, or some similar app that will give you fine grain control over root priviledges.

Comment: @AndrewD I don't have SU in my mobile. how to diable it?

Comment: @Umair min sdk is 17

Comment: The question isn't about pushing files! It's about monitor. **Device monitor** wasn't just a file explorer, so your answer is more suitable for a comment

Comment: there is also **Layout Inspector**

Comment: @user924 ok that means 39 people upvoted it because the answer was wrong ?. Read the question again :) and if you have some problem add your answer or add a comment.

Comment: @Umair you can read again it too, author didn't mention file explorer anywhere, he didn't accept your answer, there is nothing wrong with your answer's votes, other users who voted your answer needed only file explorer (other users has nothing to do with original question), but full answer should contain every tools including layout inspector, before there was only one tool - Device monitor, but now it's replaced with a couple of tools

Comment: @user924 why don't you add an answer by yourself. Instead of criticism and wasting time be positive and add something useful to the community. Thank you

Answer (score 38):

Now you can use **device file explorer** instead of **device monitor**. Go to

> view > tool windows > device file explorer

[screenshot: opening device file explorer in android studio 3.1.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nny7S.png)

**More details**

1. Click View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer or click the Device File Explorer button in the tool window bar to open the Device File Explorer.
2. Select a device from the drop down list.
3. Interact with the device content in the file explorer window. Right-click on a file or directory to create a new file or directory, save the selected file or directory to your machine, upload, delete, or synchronize. Double-click a file to open it in Android Studio.

Android Studio saves files you open this way in a temporary directory outside of your project. If you make modifications to a file you opened using the Device File Explorer, and would like to save your changes back to the device, you must manually upload the modified version of the file to the device.

[screenshot: The Device File Explorer tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGlCc.png)

When exploring a device's files, the following directories are particularly useful:

> data/data/app_name/

Contains data files for your app stored on internal storage

> sdcard/

Contains user files stored on external user storage (pictures, etc.)

> Note: Not all files on a hardware device are visible in the Device
>   File Explorer. For example, in the data/data/ directory, entries
>   corresponding to apps on the device that are not debuggable cannot be
>   expanded in the Device File Explorer.

Comment: **device monitor** wasn't just a file explorer, so your answer is more suitable for a comment

Comment: there is also **Layout Inspector**

Answer (score 21):

To start the standalone Device Monitor application, enter the following on the command line in the **`android-sdk/tools/`** directory:

```
monitor
```

You can then link the tool to a connected device by selecting the device from the **Devices** pane. If you have trouble viewing panes or **windows, select Window > Reset Perspective** from the menu bar.

- **Note:** Each device can be attached to only one debugger process at a time. So, for example, if you are using Android Studio to debug your app on a device, you need to disconnect the Android Studio debugger from the device before you attach a debugger process from the Android Device Monitor.

reference : https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

**=>** You Can change **`minSdkVersion 16`** And open **Device File Explorer**

- ***Device File Explorer*** work same as a ***Android Device Monitor***

See Below Image:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From Android Studio 3.1 [Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#device_monitor_available_from_the_command_line) available from the command line only.

> In Android Studio 3.1, the Device Monitor serves less of a role than
>   it previously did. In many cases, the functionality available through
>   the Device Monitor is now provided by new and improved tools.
>
> See the [Device Monitor documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) for instructions for invoking the
>   Device Monitor from the command line and for details of the tools
>   available through the Device Monitor.

To start the standalone Device Monitor application, enter the following on the command line in the **`android-sdk/tools/`** directory:

```
monitor
```

Comment: Yes i am able to get it from command line. but what about from studio. it is not feasible solution

Comment: As per release note : Device Monitor serves less of a role than it previously did. May be that's why they remove that option.

Answer (score 5):

To start the standalone Device Monitor application, enter the following on the command line in the  **android-sdk/tools/ directory:**

`monitor`

But remember 
**Most of the Android Device Monitor componenets are deprecated after 3.0**
For detail info visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html)

[image: Android Device Monitor and its features are deprecated after 3.0]

Answer (score 5):

To get it to work I had to switch to **Java 8** from **Java 10** (In my system PATH variable) then go to 
`C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64 and run monitor.exe.`

Answer (score 3):

jdk max version is 1.8.0_144

then run monitor

Answer (score 3):

As said in ["Testing the game on your Android device"](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing?playlist=17138), I followed these three steps

1. With the game still running on your device, return to your computer.
2. Navigate to the directory containing the Android SDK Tools.
3. Navigate to tools and double click the application called monitor.

This was prompting the following error

[image: Android Device Monitor Error]

I've also tested using cmd and the same error persisted

[image: cmd]

To fix it, I had to go to **AndroidSDKTools\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64** and double click in the monitor application

[image: monitor application]

And then the Android Device Manager just started as normal

[image: Android Device Manager]

Comment: if i want to use in the cmd just the 'monitor' command i have to add this folder 'AndroidSDKTools\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64' to the environment paths of windows?

Comment: now i can confirm: if you want to use in the cmd just the 'monitor' command you have to add this folder 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64' (in my case with android studio 3.4.1) to the environment variables => system variables => path and restart the cmd window if you had it opened

Answer (score 2):

You still can run it from File explorer on Windows 10 with the proper path. You just need to go to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64` and double click the file monitor.

If you want to use in the cmd just the 'monitor' command you have to add this folder (in my case with android studio 3.4.1 and win10) to your Environment variables. So, press the start button and then type `Edit the system environment variabes` click it and System properties window should open. Then go to

> Environment variables => System variables => path

press the `Edit` button for path and add the new value

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64

click 'Ok', 'Ok' and 'Ok' and restart the cmd window if you had it opened and type 'monitor' and it should open the monitor as well.

Hope it helps!

PD: This answer was based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077068/5360905 from [Tiago Martins Peres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5675325/tiago-martins-peres)

Answer (score 1):

ADM was deprecated in 3.1 version of android studio and removed from Android Studio 3.2. Android Device Monitor have been replaced by new features and to start Android Device Monitor application in android studio 3.1 and lower, following the commend line `android-sdk/tools/` directory:

`monitor`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the Hierarchy Viewer tool, it has been changed to Layout Inspector:

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html

Answer (score 1):

> Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2

Use [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html) introduced in Android Studio 3.0 to measure the cpu utilisation, network, memory etc,. To open Android Profiler: View -> Tool Windows -> Profiler.

Android Device Monitor has been replaced by some new feature which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor).

Answer (score 0):

According to developer docs, it's deprecated now. Please follow these docs:
[developer link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 3.1 and above, you can push photos to the emulator, by first starting the emulator. Then select “Device File Explorer” from the menu at the top of the screen:    View/Tool Window/Device File Explorer
Then look in the folder titled “sdcard” and you will see a folder titled “Pictures”, click on it.
Then right click it and select “Upload” and navigate to the photo on your computer, to the photo you would like to push onto the emulator. The restart the emulator.
See photo below:
[example of uploading a photo to emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTSLV.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor) out.

Open your terminal and type: **Android_Sdk_Path/tools**

Run **./monitor**