# Device Monitor is not showing in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, ddms

I cannot open Device Monitor in my Android Studio SDK because its icon literally disappeared from the drop-down list in the tools menu option. I do not know if there's any other access point or icon or term in the menus to open the Device Monitor.

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 for 64 bits. 
Also, when I go to the directory:

```
Android/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64,
```

I do find the next file:

```
monitor.exe
```

but if I try to open it through:

```
 sudo ./monitor ,
```

I get:

```
command not found
```

(besides, being a .exe it's for M$, not for Linux, so...?). 
So it appears that Device Monitor is not installed at all (but it was fully functional before and normally showing its icon).

This is strange because everything else is working fine in my Android Studio environment. This time, my Android Studio 3.1 program was updated through Ubuntu console and not directly through the Android Studio prompt menu; there shouldn't be any difference, but it seems that this caused a problem... so is this a bug? what am I missing here? any ideas?

Comment: Your Android SDK should have `monitor` in its `tools/` directory. This works fine on my Ubuntu 17.10 environment, though you cannot have the Android Device Monitor open at the same time as Android Studio. Most features of the Android Device Monitor are now part of Studio itself, so you may not need the Monitor anymore.

Comment: What I only use from Device Monitor is a way to push and pull files from the SDCard emulator. So how will I be able to push/pull the files that I need to work with? (Apart from dropping them into the start page of your emulated phone, which is a push. But how to eliminate the files?)

Comment: Use Device File Explorer, available in Android Studio 3.0+. Or, use `adb push`, `adb pull`, and `adb shell`, if you prefer the command line.

Comment: Yes Android Device Monitor is not available in Android Studio 3.1 But 
**Device File Explorer** is work like a Android Device Monitor See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574127/how-to-open-android-device-monitor-in-latest-android-studio-3-1/49574244#49574244