# How to open Android Device Monitor in latest Android Studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

After updating my Android studio i did not found Android Device Monitor, which should be appear in 'Tools' Sections.So at this moment I'm in trouble with adding database. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkG74.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Android Device Monitor in latest Android Studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574127/how-to-open-android-device-monitor-in-latest-android-studio-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

> `Android Device Monitor` **was deprecated** in Android Studio 3.1 and
>   **removed from Android Studio 3.2**. The features that you could use
>   through the Android Device Monitor have been replaced by new features.

You should be able to use [**Android Profiler**](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) nowadays.

Check this link for the other options and the table of tools: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Comment: Thank u for your help.