# Android ADB: How to push multiple files, into an emulator?

Tags: android, adb

I'm using ADB in order to copy files from my desktop to a folder on my emulator.

> adb push pic.jpg '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/

This works fine, but I have many files I would like to copy, and I don't want to repeat this command for every file. How can I "push" the contents of a whole directory?

Edit: screenshot of my Android studio:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For uploading the whole directory, the easiest way is to use Device File Manager in Android Studio.

Open it from the bottom right toolbar and navigate to the directory in the device where you want to upload the data.

[image: Device File Manager]

Right click and click on upload to upload files or directory.

Note: Works only in Android Studio 3.0 and above

Comment: I'm using the latest Android studio, and just can't find that thing anywhere. I do not have that item: View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer, or any icon on the bottom right.

Comment: Is it possible this doesn't exist in the Windows version?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: According to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49574244/9636037 minSdkVersion must be 16 or above. (Which I find to be irrelevant) What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: I don't know what that is, and where to find it :D Anyway i see in my "event log", various errors, like: Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037. Do you think it's related?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193218/discussion-between-abhi-and-sheff2k1).

Answer (score 1):

To push everything in the current directory, you can try:

```
adb push * /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tar` to put all your files into a single archive:

```sh
tar -cvf all.tar .
```

Then push that archive to the device:

```sh
adb push all.tar  /sdcard
```

Finally untar your tar file in the device:

```sh
adb shell tar -xvf /sdcard/all.tar -C /sdcard
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution so I made one:

```
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient
import os
import glob

adb = AdbClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=5037)
devices = adb.devices()    #List of all connected devices


def send_over_adb(device,hostpath,devpath="/storage/emulated/0/"):      # Recursively send folder and files over adb
    if os.path.isfile(hostpath):
        devpath = os.path.join(devpath,hostpath).replace('\\','/') # optimization for windows
        device.push(hostpath, devpath)
    elif os.path.isdir(hostpath):
        for i in glob.glob(hostpath+'\*'):
            print(i)
            send_over_adb(device,i,devpath)
    device.shell('am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard')
    device.shell('am force-stop com.android.gallery3d') #force create thumbnails


hostpath='\path\to\folder\or\file\'
send_over_adb(devices[0],hostpath,devpath)
```

This function recursively sends over the folders and files while maintaining folder structure and ignores empty directories.

Limitation: file name shouldn't contain forward or back slashes(idk if any os allows that though)

Dependency: pure-python-adb

Tested on: Python3.7.9 on Win 8.1